# Native application interraction with browser extentions

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari

An external native application should communicate with browser extensions, e.g. send information to browsers what information to fill on web pages.

Those plugins or browser extensions are not yet developed, but I need to support at least Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

What kind of technology can be used to communicate external application with browser extensions? I checked Chrome and it has native messaging for these kind of cases, but I need generic solution what should work for other browsers as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic solution to compatible with all browsers at the moment. So you have to develop different extensions by using different ways for different browsers.

For Safari, you can see here 
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/CommunicatingwithyourOSXApplication/CommunicatingwithyourOSXApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH23-SW4
But unfortunately, it only supports from Safari 9.0 and OSX 10.10

For Chrome, you already know that Native Messaging is the right choice.

For Firefox, you can create a server socket, and listen to specific port. While your native application communicate with Firefox extension through the port. You can find an example here: [TcpSocket listen on Firefox addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326301/tcpsocket-listen-on-firefox-addon)