# data send by firefox tcp socket.send() can't retrive until close the socket

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, tcpsocket

I'm trying to send some data from Firefox to java desktop application .so my java class work as a server and Firefox script work as a client .when i test it using another java class which is `client.java` data successfully sent to  `server.java` how ever when i use this firefox script to send data ,it actually connect to the server .but `send("text");` doesn't work realtime .i mean sever shows received data when i close the socket `socket.close();` . but i know there is no problem with `server.java` code.

this doesn't work

```
setTimeout(function(){socket.send("i'm firefox");},5000); // because socket isn't closed yet
```

this work

```
setTimeout(function(){socket.send("i'm firefox");},5000);
setTimeout(function(){socket.close();},6000);
```

but i really don't want to close the socket because i want to send lot of data one by one.

here is the complete code tested on scratchpad [-browser]

```
var tcpSocket = Cc["@mozilla.org/tcp-socket;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMTCPSocket);
var socket = tcpSocket.open("127.0.0.1", 5000);

setTimeout(function(){socket.send("i'm firefox");},5000);
//setTimeout(function(){socket.close();},8000);// i'm firefox text retrieve by server when run this line / when close the socket.
```

i think java code isn't important.but [here](http://pastebin.com/pGmHBPPs) it is.

I'm asking why do i need to close the socket to send data ? and how can i send data without close the socket ?

---

update

[i made a Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tuou4.gif) to show my problem here you can see data not sending real time but when socket is closed all the data flushed .

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually working. Your data is being received, but you're currently waiting for a new line to print your received messages:

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Server: " + inputLine);
    out.println(inputLine);

    if (inputLine.equals("Bye.")) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Which currently only happens when you close the socket. Just add a new line at the end of your messages and it will work as expected:

```
var tcpSocket = Cc["@mozilla.org/tcp-socket;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMTCPSocket);
var socket    = tcpSocket.open("127.0.0.1", 5000);

function sendMessage(msg){
    socket.send(msg + "\n");
}

setTimeout(function(){
    sendMessage("hi mark");
},3000);

setTimeout(function(){
    sendMessage("hi johnny");
},5000);
```

Comment: ohh thanks you so much.i never thought about this. i thought something wrong on my addon script.