# How to use websocket in background scripts Firefox-addon

Tags: node.js, websocket, firefox-addon, jpm

I'm using `jpm` to develop firefox addon
I want to use `Websocket` in the firefox addon.Not in the content scripts but in the `index.js`[Background]

But it is throwing

```
JPM [error]   Message: ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined
```

Then I tried by using the [thirdparty modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Using_third-party_modules_%28jpm%29) way

But for that it's throwing dependent module not present

```
 Module `x` is not found at resource
```

I have tried to install those x modules by `npm install -x --save` .
Still it's throwing the same error

Comment: Definitely dont use third party modules it wont work. Im not sure how to do it in webextensions yet, but you have to use a FrameWorker in non-webext.

Comment: @FastSnail has some experience with sockets and had a nice question it. I'm not too familiar with sockets but check this topic out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556786/data-send-by-firefox-tcp-socket-send-cant-retrive-until-close-the-socket

Comment: @LcSalazar has another solution which is quite nice over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326301/tcpsocket-listen-on-firefox-addon?lq=1